# WPF MVVM + How to have two controls bound to different properties?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a WPF application using MVVM pattern.

On a user control I have two DataGrid's that have their ItemsSource bound to two different properties.

One of the DataGrid's is populated correctly, but the other isn't.

I can't figure out what is wrong with the binding. I have tried explicitly setting the DataContext of the DataGrid not working but am not sure why I should have to do this, or where to do it.

I have verified the retrieving of the data is working as I can debug and see the data, and the DataGrid has rows that are 'clickable', there just is no text showing.

AssignItemsToCategoryViewModel.cs

```
/// <summary>
    /// Describes the name that will be used for the menu option
    /// Implemented from IPageViewModel
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Assign Items To Categories "; }

    }

    #region Categories
    private CategoryModel _currentCategory;
    public CategoryModel CurrentCategory
    {
        get { return _currentCategory; }
        set
        {
            _currentCategory = value;              
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCategory");
        }       
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> Categories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryModel>();

    public RelayCommand GetCategoriesRelay;

    public AssignItemsToCategoryViewModel ()
    {
        CurrentCategory = new CategoryModel();
        CurrentStockItem = new StockItemModel();
    }

    #region Get Categories Command
    /// <summary>
    /// The interface command
    /// to run the get GetCategories method
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand GetCategoriesCommand
    {
        get
        {
            GetCategoriesRelay = new RelayCommand(p => GetCategories(),
                p => CanGetCategories());

            return GetCategoriesRelay;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks whether the GetCategories command can be run
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True or False</returns>
    private bool CanGetCategories()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to fetch the categories
    /// </summary>
    private void GetCategories()
    {
        Categories = CurrentCategory.GetCategories();
        ReceivedCategories = Categories;

        if (Categories.Any())
            SelectedIndex = 0;

    }

    #endregion


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the DataGrid's selected index
    /// Used to set the index to 0 if any categories exist.
    /// </summary>
    private int _selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of received categories
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> ReceivedCategories
    {
        get { return Categories; }

        set
        {
            Categories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ReceivedCategories");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Stock Items

    private StockItemModel _currentStockItem;
    public StockItemModel CurrentStockItem
    {
        get { return _currentStockItem; }
        set
        {
            _currentStockItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentStockItem");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<StockItemModel> StockItems = new ObservableCollection<StockItemModel>();

    public RelayCommand GetStockItemsRelay;
    public RelayCommand LinkItemRelay;
    public RelayCommand UnlinkItemRelay;


    #region Get Stock Items Command

    /// <summary>
    /// The interface command
    /// to run the get GetStockItems method
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand GetStockItemsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            GetStockItemsRelay = new RelayCommand(p => GetStockItems(),
                p => CanGetStockItems());

            return GetStockItemsRelay;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks whether the GetStockItems command can be run
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True or False</returns>
    private bool CanGetStockItems()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to fetch the stock items
    /// </summary>
    private void GetStockItems()
    {
        StockItems = CurrentStockItem.GetStockItems();
        ReceivedStockItems = StockItems;

        if (ReceivedStockItems.Any())
            SelectedStockItemIndex = 0;

    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Stock Items DataGrid's selected index
    /// Used to set the index to 0 if any stock items exist.
    /// </summary>
    private int _selectedStockItemIndex;
    public int SelectedStockItemIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedStockItemIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedStockItemIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStockItemIndex");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the CurerntStockItem Id
    /// </summary>
    public long? StockLinkId
    {
        get { return CurrentStockItem.StockLink; }
        set
        {
            CurrentStockItem.StockLink = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StockLinkId");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the CurrentStockItem ItemCode
    /// </summary>
    public string ItemCode
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentStockItem.ItemCode;
        }
        set
        {
            CurrentStockItem.ItemCode = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("ItemCode");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of received categories
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<StockItemModel> ReceivedStockItems
    {
        get { return StockItems; }

        set
        {
            StockItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ReceivedStockItems");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

AssignItemsToCategoryView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SalesLinker.View.AssignItemsToCategoryView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"      
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600" Background="White">

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetCategoriesCommand}" />
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetStockItemsCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}"  >

        <HeaderedContentControl x:Name="ItemsList"   
                                Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"
                                Header="Items">

            <DataGrid x:Name="LstItems" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"  IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ReceivedStockItems, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" GridLinesVisibility="None"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" Background="White"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedStockItemIndex}" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ItemCode}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Item Code" Width="300" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
    </Border>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" >

            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
                <Button Command="{Binding LinkItemCommand}"  Height="50" Width="50"  Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TbDescription, Path=Text}">
                <Image Source="/Images/RightArrow.png"/>
            </Button>

            <Button Command="{Binding UnlinkItemCommand}"    Height="50" Width="50" Background="Transparent"  BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem.CategoryID, ElementName=LstCategories, Mode=OneWay }" >
                <Image Source="/Images/LeftArrow.png"/>
            </Button>

        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>


    <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}"  >

        <HeaderedContentControl x:Name="CategoryItems"   
                                Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"
                                Header="Categories">

            <DataGrid x:Name="LstCategories" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"  IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ReceivedCategories, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" GridLinesVisibility="None"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" Background="White"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex}">


                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Path=Description}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Description" Width="300" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

The DataGrid named LstCategories works as expected, but LstItems is the problem.

Comment: There's too much stuff in your question for me to comb through to see where the problem is.  In future, help us help you by creating a minimal version of your code that demonstrates your problem. 70% of the time just doing this will answer your question, as you figure out your mistake (protip: it's hidden in the haystack of all that other code).  Also, the output window should have binding errors. Check them? If not, go search for debugging binding errors. Lastly, get Snoop and examine your bindings at runtime. That also sometimes helps.

Comment: Thanks Will, snoop helped me find my so silly mistake.

Comment: That's great.  I scanned through your code, and would have seen something that obvious, but there was just too much for the time I had.  It is really really important that you pair down your code when asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was really silly. I guess if I had shown my model class, the majority of people would have spotted it immediately.

I forgot to add the getter and setter to my property on my model class

So I had

```
public string ItemCode;
```

instead of:

```
public string ItemCode {get; set;}
```